# ng-click doesn't work with md-button

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

My html and javascript are as follows, I have the following element

```
<i class="material-icons" ng-click="clicked()" md-48>add_circle</i>
```

Which works when clicked i.e. by bringing up a dialog, however the following on the same page does not work.

html

```
<body ng-cloak>
  <div ng-cloak ng-controller="mainController" >
    <div layout="row" layout-align="end end">
      <md-button aria-label="Eat cake" ng-click="clicked()"></md-button>
     </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

angular

```
angular.module('notifyMe', ['ngMaterial', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

    .controller('mainController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.clicked = function () {
        alert('Worked!');
    };
    })
```

Comment: You didn't forget the `ng-app` directive, did you?

Comment: nope :), had it in `<html lang="en" ng-app="notifyMe">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your code should work. Make sure you loaded the dependencies as below:

**DEMO**

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module('webapp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.clicked = function () {
        alert('Worked!');
    };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="webapp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/hammerjs/2.0.4/hammer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Use dev version of Angular Material -->
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div layout="column" layout-fill flex style="max-height:100%">
    <md-toolbar>
      <md-button ng-click=clicked()>Click here</md-button>
    </md-toolbar>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```